# Google Analytic Code, Error is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-analytics, literals

after adding Google Analytic code on my website  website is not working and showing error.

**This page isn’t is currently unable to handle this request.**
**HTTP ERROR 500**

Other codes are working fine, Like I tried to past **alert("hello");**
and its working and showing alert, but only New Google Analytic Code is not working.

**myy header code which is not working**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>{settings('site_title')}</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link id="bootstrapStyle" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/components/bootstrap5/css/blue.css?v={time()}">
    <!-- Lib -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/evolution/css/global.css?v={time()}">

{block name="css"}{/block}


   <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-******"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-******');
</script>


</head>
```

On my same page I have old Analytic code in footer already which is working somehow,

Can you please guide how I can change this code to **new one?** which I shared above? Because When I am pasting new code inside this, its showing same error again.

```
 {if settings('googleanalytics') == 'yes'}
     var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '{settings('googleanalyticsid')}']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    {literal}
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
    {/literal}
    {/if}
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message that basically can mean anything. Check your web servers error log to find out what the actual error message is to narrow the issue down.

Comment: I am sorry but this issue occurs only when I put this specific Google Analytic Code, Other javascript codes are working fine.

Comment: Please read my first comment again. Find the error message and it will most likely help you locate the issue. That's debugging 101.

Comment: Is it your server or google that's generating the 500?

Comment: my error_log is not showing any latest error after this issue, only the old ones.